# How to send two data to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send two things to my ajax file. The first one is a formular (method POST) and the second is a simple string.

I can send the form like this :

```
$.post('ajaxDialog.php', $('#sol').serialize(),function(responseObject,ioArgs) ...
```

And it works but if I try to send two things like that :

```
$.post('ajaxDialog.php', {$('#sol').serialize(),simpleString},function(responseObject,ioArgs)
```

I have an error. So I tried to pass `$('#sol').serialize()` into an array :

```
var arrayForm = $('#sol').serialize();
```

I can't get the values of my form with `$_POST['fieldName']` with this method. How should I do ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`serialize` returns a url encoded query string, in the format: `"key=val&anotherkey=anotherval"` To append to it, just add your new key value pair, seperated by an ambersand `&`:

```
$.post('ajaxDialog.php', 
       $('#sol').serialize()+"&somestring="+simpleString,
       function(responseObject,ioArgs){});
```

Comment: I understand. And after, I could use `$_POST['simpleString']` in my ajax file ? Or how should I get this value ?

Comment: @Lison well if you use my code exactly, it would be `$_POST['somestring']`, basically whatever you set the key too